# for: Command not found on gnome terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, tar

Long and short of it: I have a folder full of 1583 `.tar` files. Each `.ta`r file contains only one folder, and i want a folder full of only those folders. Trying to do this using console commands because i cant figure out how to get python to do it for me. By reading around online i've come up with the command

```
for file in ls *.tar do; do tar -xzf $file -C /path/to/destination/folder done
```

Error comes up:

```
for: command not found
```

Unsure what to do about this. Everywhere i look about how to get for loops to work in linux terminals and everywhere is just saying "

> write `for x; do y`

with no advice on how to actually get that stuff to work...

I'm hearing a lot about linux bash and scripting and stuff... I dont really understand what all these things are. Do i need to perform some ritual to get bash to work? Apparently ls and cd and stuff are part of bash too? Those are working fine for me, but for loops are not...

Sorry if this is really basic guys, i'm kind of computer illiterate.

Thanks for any help!!

--

ok it asked me to write 2 sections and i came up with the following after i had already written the above:

---

as stated before, I've come up with the command

```
for file in ls *.tar do; do tar -xzf $file -C /path/to/destination/folder done
```

Using `tar -xzf` manually works just fine, even puts it in the right folder. But i dont want to just do that manually (because of the 1500+ files thing) and the `tar` command wont take `*.tar` as an input - I looked up how to solve this problem and was fed the command I tried to use as a fix.

Thanks again!!

Jude S

Comment: "for: Command not found" looks like an error message from csh (or tcsh). They have *very* different syntax from bash. Make sure you're using the right syntax for the shell you're actually using (or switch shells if necessary).

Comment: @GordonDavisson: `csh` and `tcsh` would give `for: No match.`.

Comment: @LjmDullaart That's the error message you get if `*.tar` doesn't match any files. It apparently takes precedence over the "Command not found" error.

Comment: @GordonDavisson you are right; I'll adjust my answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are some syntax-errors in the command. But `bash` should understand `for`. Are you sure you are using `bash` and not a `csh` or `tcsh`?

To be sure (for test purposes) you can just type

```
bash
```

and that will start a bash-shell for you.

As for the syntax-errors: the command should probably be:

```
for file in *.tar ; do tar xzf "$file" -C /path/to/destination/folder ; done
```

On the other hand, if you want keep using your (t)csh, it would be something like:

```
foreach file ( *.tar )
tar xzf $file -C /path/to/destination/folder
end
```